# Rails:what's the different between 'Get' and 'Resources' ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

trying to create a route on rails and i just wonna understand the different
between 'Get' and 'Resources'.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

when you use `get` verb you create only 1 route that is createad as `get` for route you match.
`get /photos` createas route with verb `get` for route `/photos`

When you use `resources` it creates 7 routes, for example:
`resources :photos` will generate

```
GET     /photos     photos#index    display a list of all photos
GET     /photos/new     photos#new  return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST    /photos     photos#create   create a new photo
GET     /photos/:id     photos#show     display a specific photo
GET     /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit     return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT   /photos/:id     photos#update   update a specific photo
DELETE  /photos/:id photos#destroy  delete a specific photo
```

Check also

[Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)